# Python or Java as Backend Language in Google App engine?

Tags: java, android, python, google-app-engine

I am developing an application in Android using `Google App` engine and `Google Compute Engine` as backend .

I have followed the Google's demo code in python as base for my application.

Now I have question in my mind that since I am more familiar with Java then Python and also need to consider the fact that Google is supporting Python more then Java in its most of the demo codes, Should I change my GAE backend language to Java??

I should stick with Python and hope that I would come around with Python eventually.

Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks

Comment: If you know Java, I would suggest you continue with Java.

Comment: Voting for close. This is a typically opinion based question.

Comment: if you are good in java,than stick to java only.

Comment: Alright I agree , but what if I say that most of the demo code(Python)of GAE that I am using in my application is not available in Java and I am having hard time to implement the Google App Engine Apis in Java?

Comment: Python is better if you plan to code alone and starting from a beginner level. Java can appear more solid but it's just only more complicated I think, especially if you want to use the App Engine Datastore in your app. In general if you plan to develop a native app better Java, for a web app with GAE I would say totally Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can really go with either, to be honest, and use whatever suits your style.

When I started using App Engine, I was Java all the way. I recently switched to Python and love it too!

If you have a lot of existing java dependencies, such as libraries etc. that you want to continue using, then stick with it. Otherwise, it's worth dipping your toe in the Python waters.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.At this point I am really building a foundation of my own style. Thats why want to confirm which way to go

Comment: The nice thing I discovered, going from no knowledge with Python to building a very large application, is that it was super easy to learn. So not much of a time investment in order to widen my skill range. Just my 2 cents. Good luck with it! :)

Answer (score 4):

Here are some points to consider:

- Both Python and Java are capable languages and App Engine Services are available to a large extent in both the environments.
- You should use the environment that you are most comfortable with. This will help when debugging issues on the Server side. I would go with the language that I am most familiar with in case the application is critical, is on a tight deadline, etc. If you are learning the environment and have the time, it is great to look at a new language.
- Since you are writing an Android application that is interacting with your Server side application in App Engine, one assumes that you would be exposing this functionality over Web Services. Both Python and Java environments are capable of hosting Web Services. In fact, with Google Cloud Endpoints, you should be able to even generate client side bindings (client libraries) for Android that integrate easily.

Comment: Alright I agree , but what if I say that most of the demo code(Python)of GAE that I am using in my application is not available in Java and I am having hard time to implement the Google App Engine Apis in Java?

Comment: To a large extent, I am quite sure you will be able to implement the functionality in either of the 2 languages, given the focus and time. I would repeat that if you look at the services available on App Engine, both Java and Python have comparable services. The rest of it would really be your application logic.